# Crash JRE libc.so.6 with HTTPS

Tags: jvm, segmentation-fault

I have googled all the planet without any solution to my problem.

Here is the hs_err_pid.log start file and the end

Let me know if you have any clue, because I have no idea how to solve it.
Excuse me for the presentation, I am beginner.
Thank you guys

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5589b6c480, pid=7353, tid=139994995676928
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_121) (build 1.7.0_121-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.121-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.8
# Distribution: Gentoo Base System release 2.2, package Gentoo icedtea-7.2.6.8
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x8e480]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/tomcat/7.0.78/logs/core or core.7353
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f558012a000):  JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-2" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=7775, stack(0x00007f531fbcd000,0x00007f531ffce000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0xfffffff84484b640, RBX=0x00007f558012a000, RCX=0x000000000911ea30, RDX=0x000000000488f518
RSP=0x00007f531ffcbe98, RBP=0x00007f531ffcbf10, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00000007b6f254a8
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007f5580018598, R10=0x000000000488f528, R11=0xfffffffffffffff8
R12=0x000000000488f518, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f558012a1d8, R15=0x00007f5505578620
RIP=0x00007f5589b6c480, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0f19000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f531ffcbe98)
0x00007f531ffcbe98:   00007f5589092baa 00007f558012a000
0x00007f531ffcbea8:   0000000000000000 00007f558012a000
0x00007f531ffcbeb8:   0000000000000000 00007f531ffcbee0
0x00007f531ffcbec8:   00007f55890a3d9b 00007f558012a000
0x00007f531ffcbed8:   bb924a63a8aa2700 00007f531ffcbf10
0x00007f531ffcbee8:   00007f558012a000 00007f558012a1d8
0x00007f531ffcbef8:   00007f5505578620 000000000488f518
0x00007f531ffcbf08:   0000000000000000 00007f531ffcbf60
0x00007f531ffcbf18:   00007f55890a80f1 00007f558012a1d8
0x00007f531ffcbf28:   000000000488f3b0 00007f531ffcbf60
0x00007f531ffcbf38:   00007f558012a1d8 00007f5505578620
0x00007f531ffcbf48:   00007f550488f3b0 00007f531ffcc0a8
0x00007f531ffcbf58:   0000000000000042 00007f531ffcbf90
0x00007f531ffcbf68:   00007f55033c8150 00007f5504821850
0x00007f531ffcbf78:   00007f558012a1d8 00007f5504821850
0x00007f531ffcbf88:   00007f5505578618 00007f531ffcc010
0x00007f531ffcbf98:   00007f55033c82ba 0000000400c80ec8
0x00007f531ffcbfa8:   000000428012afe8 00007f550488f2a0
0x00007f531ffcbfb8:   00007f550488ea90 00007f531ffcc000
0x00007f531ffcbfc8:   00007f55048218a0 000000b80000000a
0x00007f531ffcbfd8:   bb924a63a8aa2700 0000000400c80ec8
0x00007f531ffcbfe8:   0000000400c80ec8 0000000000000000
0x00007f531ffcbff8:   0000000400c80ec0 00007f531ffcc0b0
0x00007f531ffcc008:   00007f558012a000 00007f531ffcc080
0x00007f531ffcc018:   00007f557d014e98 00007f558012b008
0x00007f531ffcc028:   00007f558012b008 00007f53fffffffe
0x00007f531ffcc038:   0000000000000000 00007f531ffcc040
0x00007f531ffcc048:   0000000400c80ec0 00007f531ffcc0b0
0x00007f531ffcc058:   0000000400c81ff8 0000000000000000
0x00007f531ffcc068:   0000000400c80ec8 0000000000000000
0x00007f531ffcc078:   00007f531ffcc0a0 00007f531ffcc0f8
0x00007f531ffcc088:   00007f557d00634b 0000000617228f10 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f5589b6c480)
0x00007f5589b6c460:   48 89 f0 48 8d 0c 12 48 29 f8 48 29 d0 48 39 c8
0x00007f5589b6c470:   0f 82 07 01 00 00 48 83 fa 10 0f 86 8b 01 00 00
0x00007f5589b6c480:   f3 44 0f 6f 06 48 83 fa 20 f3 44 0f 7f 07 f3 44
0x00007f5589b6c490:   0f 6f 44 16 f0 f3 44 0f 7f 44 17 f0 77 12 48 89 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0xfffffff84484b640 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f558012a000 is a thread
RCX=0x000000000911ea30 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000488f518 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f531ffcbe98 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f558012a000
RBP=0x00007f531ffcbf10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f558012a000
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000007b6f254a8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f5580018598 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000000488f528 is an unknown value
R11=0xfffffffffffffff8 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000000488f518 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007f558012a1d8 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f5505578620 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f531fbcd000,0x00007f531ffce000],  sp=0x00007f531ffcbe98,  free space=4091k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x8e480]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6380f1]
C  [libsunec.so+0x1150]
C  [libsunec.so+0x12ba]  Java_sun_security_ec_ECKeyPairGenerator_generateECKeyPair+0x12a
j  sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(I[B[B)[Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()Ljava/security/KeyPair;+55
j  java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair()Ljava/security/KeyPair;+23
j  sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/SecureRandom;)V+28
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.setupEphemeralECDHKeys()Z+88
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.trySetCipherSuite(Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;)Z+638
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(Lsun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ClientHello;)V+119
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(Lsun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ClientHello;)V+1134
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(BI)V+127
j  sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop()V+96
j  sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V+24
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V+353
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake()V+84
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Z)V+13
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSession;+10
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.handshake(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+4
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+30
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x608a84]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6077ae]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6441af]
V  [libjvm.so+0x940fba]
V  [libjvm.so+0x94135a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x803842]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(I[B[B)[Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()Ljava/security/KeyPair;+55
j  java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair()Ljava/security/KeyPair;+23
j  sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/SecureRandom;)V+28
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.setupEphemeralECDHKeys()Z+88
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.trySetCipherSuite(Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;)Z+638
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(Lsun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ClientHello;)V+119
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(Lsun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage$ClientHello;)V+1134
j  sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(BI)V+127
j  sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop()V+96
j  sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V+24
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V+353
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake()V+84
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Z)V+13
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSession;+10
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.handshake(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+4
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+30
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f55802e0800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7785, stack(0x00007f531d3c3000,0x00007f531d7c4000)]
  0x00007f55802de800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7784, stack(0x00007f531d7c4000,0x00007f531dbc5000)]
  0x00007f55802dc800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7783, stack(0x00007f531dbc5000,0x00007f531dfc6000)]
  0x00007f55802da800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7782, stack(0x00007f531dfc6000,0x00007f531e3c7000)]
```

.....

```
VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1715712K, used 1187554K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1321984K, 73% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007bb7b49c0,0x00000007d0b00000)
  from space 393728K, 54% used [0x00000007e7f80000,0x00000007f4f84178,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 381440K, 0% used [0x00000007d0b00000,0x00000007d0b00000,0x00000007e7f80000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 987789K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x000000063c4a35d8,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 531336K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 12% used [0x0000000400000000,0x00000004206e23c8,0x0000000500000000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f5584d73000,0x00007f5586d74000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f5582d73000

Polling page: 0x00007f558a6c7000

Code Cache  [0x00007f557d000000, 0x00007f557dec0000, 0x00007f5580000000)
 total_blobs=4948 nmethods=4244 adapters=664 free_code_cache=34359Kb largest_free_block=34927552

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 133.271 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 nmethod 4792 0x00007f557ddd32d0 code [0x00007f557ddd3400, 0x00007f557ddd3498]
Event: 133.282 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 4793             sun.nio.cs.CharsetMapping::readCharArray (112 bytes)
Event: 133.288 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 nmethod 4793 0x00007f557de74210 code [0x00007f557de74360, 0x00007f557de74778]
Event: 133.291 Thread 0x00007f55800c1000 nmethod 4791 0x00007f557de78d50 code [0x00007f557de78f40, 0x00007f557de7a1d0]
Event: 133.331 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 4794 %           java.util.Properties$LineReader::readLine @ 21 (452 bytes)
Event: 133.339 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 nmethod 4794% 0x00007f557dd8e110 code [0x00007f557dd8e2a0, 0x00007f557dd8eb98]
Event: 133.456 Thread 0x00007f55800c1000 4795             java.util.Properties$LineReader::readLine (452 bytes)
Event: 133.465 Thread 0x00007f55800c1000 nmethod 4795 0x00007f557dd89cd0 code [0x00007f557dd89e60, 0x00007f557dd8a618]
Event: 133.838 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 4796             org.postgresql.core.Parser::parseSingleQuotes (134 bytes)
Event: 133.841 Thread 0x00007f55800be800 nmethod 4796 0x00007f557de1d810 code [0x00007f557de1d960, 0x00007f557de1dbf8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 99.316 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=16 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1662464K, used 1428685K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1230848K, 100% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007cb200000,0x00000007cb200000)
  from space 431616K, 45% used [0x00000007cb200000,0x00000007d7333600,0x00000007e5780000)
  to   space 425472K, 0% used [0x00000007e6080000,0x00000007e6080000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 813260K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 12% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000631a330c8,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 412966K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 9% used [0x0000000400000000,0x0000000419349ba0,0x0000000500000000)
Event: 99.399 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=16 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1678848K, used 196634K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1253376K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007cc800000)
  from space 425472K, 46% used [0x00000007e6080000,0x00000007f2086a98,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 418304K, 0% used [0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007e6080000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 845202K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000633964900,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 412966K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 9% used [0x0000000400000000,0x0000000419349ba0,0x0000000500000000)
}
Event: 108.691 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=17 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1678848K, used 1450010K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1253376K, 100% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007cc800000)
  from space 425472K, 46% used [0x00000007e6080000,0x00000007f2086a98,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 418304K, 0% used [0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007e6080000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 845202K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 13% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000633964900,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 431803K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 10% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041a5aeec8,0x0000000500000000)
Event: 108.774 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=17 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1671680K, used 190846K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1253376K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007cc800000)
  from space 418304K, 45% used [0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007d825f840,0x00000007e6080000)
  to   space 411648K, 0% used [0x00000007e6e00000,0x00000007e6e00000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 881007K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 14% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000635c5bd70,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 431803K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 10% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041a5aeec8,0x0000000500000000)
}
Event: 114.421 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=18 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1671680K, used 1444222K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1253376K, 100% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007cc800000)
  from space 418304K, 45% used [0x00000007cc800000,0x00000007d825f840,0x00000007e6080000)
  to   space 411648K, 0% used [0x00000007e6e00000,0x00000007e6e00000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 881007K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 14% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000635c5bd70,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 447970K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 10% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041b5789f8,0x0000000500000000)
Event: 114.505 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=18 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1697280K, used 212260K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007ce780000)
  from space 411648K, 51% used [0x00000007e6e00000,0x00000007f3d49188,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 399872K, 0% used [0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007e6e00000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 913317K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 14% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000637be9728,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 447970K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 10% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041b5789f8,0x0000000500000000)
}
Event: 123.134 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=19 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1697280K, used 1497892K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 100% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007ce780000)
  from space 411648K, 51% used [0x00000007e6e00000,0x00000007f3d49188,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 399872K, 0% used [0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007e6e00000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 913317K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 14% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000637be9728,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 480230K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 11% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041d4f9b90,0x0000000500000000)
Event: 123.218 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=19 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1685504K, used 182843K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007ce780000)
  from space 399872K, 45% used [0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007d9a0ecf0,0x00000007e6e00000)
  to   space 393728K, 0% used [0x00000007e7f80000,0x00000007e7f80000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 946748K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000639c8f218,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 480230K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 11% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041d4f9b90,0x0000000500000000)
}
Event: 128.937 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=20 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1685504K, used 1468475K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1285632K, 100% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007ce780000)
  from space 399872K, 45% used [0x00000007ce780000,0x00000007d9a0ecf0,0x00000007e6e00000)
  to   space 393728K, 0% used [0x00000007e7f80000,0x00000007e7f80000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 946748K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x0000000639c8f218,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 496294K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 11% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041e4a9b58,0x0000000500000000)
Event: 129.028 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=20 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 1715712K, used 213008K [0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1321984K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x0000000780000000,0x00000007d0b00000)
  from space 393728K, 54% used [0x00000007e7f80000,0x00000007f4f84178,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 381440K, 0% used [0x00000007d0b00000,0x00000007d0b00000,0x00000007e7f80000)
 ParOldGen       total 6291456K, used 987789K [0x0000000600000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
  object space 6291456K, 15% used [0x0000000600000000,0x000000063c4a35d8,0x0000000780000000)
 PSPermGen       total 4194304K, used 496294K [0x0000000400000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000600000000)
  object space 4194304K, 11% used [0x0000000400000000,0x000000041e4a9b58,0x0000000500000000)
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 133.447 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d455ca4 method=java.lang.Character.isUpperCase(I)Z @ 5
Event: 133.447 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f557d674dac method=java.beans.Introspector.processPropertyDescriptors()V @ 91
Event: 133.448 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f557d674dac method=java.beans.Introspector.processPropertyDescriptors()V @ 91
Event: 133.448 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d4566e4 method=java.lang.Character.isUpperCase(I)Z @ 5
Event: 133.449 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f557d674dac method=java.beans.Introspector.processPropertyDescriptors()V @ 91
Event: 133.454 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d2cb5c4 method=java.nio.Buffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer; @ 33
Event: 133.459 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d7226ec method=java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;Z)Ljava/nio/charset/CoderResult; @ 1
Event: 140.285 Thread 0x00007f5580128000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557dd5c1c8 method=sun.security.util.AbstractAlgorithmConstraints.checkAlgorithm([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/security/util/AlgorithmDecomposer;)Z @ 70
Event: 140.288 Thread 0x00007f558012a000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d19cb90 method=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read([BII)I @ 70
Event: 140.289 Thread 0x00007f5580128000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f557d19cb90 method=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read([BII)I @ 70

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 133.458 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae646ec0 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.458 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae647620 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.458 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae64a7c8 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.458 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae64af78 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.459 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae64e800 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.459 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae64f008 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.460 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae652348 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 133.460 Thread 0x00007f558015f800 Threw 0x00000007ae652b58 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 135.204 Thread 0x00007f54f4d23800 Threw 0x00000007ae82a358 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322
Event: 139.962 Thread 0x00007f54f4fab000 Threw 0x00000007aed1c080 at /var/tmp/notmpfs/portage/dev-java/icedtea-7.2.6.8/work/icedtea-2.6.8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1322

Events (10 events):
Event: 140.290 loading class 0x00007f55043e2ff0
Event: 140.290 loading class 0x00007f55043e2ff0 done
Event: 140.290 loading class 0x00007f55043e2da0
Event: 140.290 loading class 0x00007f55043e2da0 done
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55043e3b30
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55043e3b30 done
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55043e3550
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55043e3550 done
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55804696e0
Event: 140.291 loading class 0x00007f55804696e0 done


Dynamic libraries:
003ff000-00400000 rw-p 00000000 08:03 18490064                           /opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.6.8/bin/java
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00001000 08:03 18490064                           /opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.6.8/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00001000 08:03 18490064                           /opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.6.8/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 18490064                           /opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.6.8/bin/java
01988000-019a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

.....

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/7.0.78/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewSize=2048m -XX:MaxNewSize=2048m -XX:PermSize=4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xcheck:jni -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=8192m -Xss4096k -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/7.0.78/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/7.0.78 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/7.0.78 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/7.0.78/temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.4
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x996df0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x996df0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x801c80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x801c80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x801c80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x801db0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x801d00], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x801d00], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x801d00], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTRAP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Gentoo Base System release 2.3

uname:Linux 4.4.6-gentoo #1 SMP Fri Jul 22 14:10:27 CEST 2016 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.23 NPTL 2.23 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 63651, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:0.44 0.27 2.74

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       16328680 kB
MemFree:         4797700 kB
MemAvailable:   11312328 kB
Buffers:          586184 kB
Cached:          6091712 kB
SwapCached:         6488 kB
Active:          7015680 kB
Inactive:        3838568 kB
Active(anon):    4578024 kB
Inactive(anon):   170920 kB
Active(file):    2437656 kB
Inactive(file):  3667648 kB
Unevictable:        7444 kB
Mlocked:            7444 kB
SwapTotal:        972796 kB
SwapFree:         860668 kB
Dirty:               460 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4183196 kB
Mapped:           712856 kB
Shmem:            566544 kB
Slab:             549900 kB
SReclaimable:     469876 kB
SUnreclaim:        80024 kB
KernelStack:       13760 kB
PageTables:        47748 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9137136 kB
Committed_AS:   17231004 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     3195776 kB
DirectMap2M:    13502464 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB


CPU:total 16 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv
```

.....
    Memory: 4k page, physical 16328680k(4797700k free), swap 972796k(860668k free)

```
vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.121-b00) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_121-b00), built on Nov 19 2016 12:19:28 by "portage" with gcc 4.9.3

time: Fri Jun 23 11:39:29 2017
elapsed time: 140 seconds
```